# Как запустить python скрипт не из терминала(консоли) Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, executable

Python 3.8
Ubuntu 20.04
GNOME 3.36.3

Здравствуйте.
Я разрабатываю консольный скрипт из под линукс. Для конечного пользователя не удобно запускать скрипт из консоли, тем более если доступ к коду будет открыт непосредственно из исходника будет не есть хорошо. С помощью pyinstaller запаковал скрипт в исполняемый файл. В начале скрипта прописана строка `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, атрибут исполнимости установлен, однако он всё так же запускается из консоли. Подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы добиться запуска скрипта не из терминала, а из файловой системы двойным кликом по файлу?

Answer (score 2):

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile  --noupx   Yourfile.py
```

--noconsole значит убрать консоль

Comment: Не работает. Всё равно запуск через консоль

Comment: c desktop файлом тоже?

Comment: Вот тут можно по подробнее? Как создать этот файл?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries_(Русский)